# How to get data form Same <form> with many <input type='file' multiple /> elements as separate set for each input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have a  with 3  tags as given below;

```
 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name[]">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone" name="phone[]">
 <input type="file" name="Image[]" id="image"  multiple />
```

I enter record of 2 persons. I select 2 images for 1st person and 3 images for 2nd person. When I submit form then I receive data as following;

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mr A
            [1] => Mr B
        )

    [phone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1234567
            [1] => 9876543
        )

    [Image] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 (1).png
            [1] => 1 (2).png
            [2] => 1 (3).png
            [3] => 1 (4).png
            [4] => 1 (5).png
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Problem is, How can I identify which images belongs to which person. I need data as separate set for each person as following

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mr A
            [1] => Mr B
        )

    [phone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1234567
            [1] => 9876543
        )

    [Image] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1 (1).png
                            [1] => 1 (2).png
                        )
            [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1 (3).png
                            [1] => 1 (4).png
                            [2] => 1 (5).png
                        )
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Please help in this context

Comment: Amend the names of the inputs per group. Are you submitting the form normally or via AJAX?

Comment: `name="name[$cnt]"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not using AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem myself. We could not send data as separate group unless we change name attribute. I have fixed by changing the name onClick

```
<input type="file" name="image[1][]" id="" onchange="countFiles()" multiple />
```

JQuery

```
function countFiles(){
 var n = $(':input[type=file]').length; //counts input type file tags
 $(event.currentTarget).attr('name', 'image['+n+'][]'); //changes name
}
```